# Passing arraylist form servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have problem with passing array object from servlet to jsp. When i try to pass it to jsp i get NullPointerException but if i print that object in servlet i have all data.

Servlet :

```
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM APP.CUSTOMER");
        CustomerBean customer = null;
        List<CustomerBean> list = new ArrayList<CustomerBean>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            customer = new CustomerBean();
            customer.setCustomer_id(rs.getInt("CUSTOMER_ID"));
            customer.setName(rs.getString("NAME"));
            customer.setPhone(rs.getString("PHONE"));
            customer.setEmail(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
            customer.setCity(rs.getString("CITY"));
            list.add(customer);
        } 
       request.getSession().setAttribute("list", list);
       RequestDispatcher disp;
       disp = getServletContext( ).getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");

       disp.forward(request, response);
```

JSP :

```
<%  
    // retrieve your list from the request, with casting 
    ArrayList<CustomerBean> list = (ArrayList<CustomerBean>) request.getAttribute("list");

    // print the information about every category of the list
    for(CustomerBean list1 : list) {
        out.println(list1.getCustomer_id());
        out.println(list1.getName());
        out.println(list1.getPhone());
        out.println(list1.getEmail());
        out.println(list1.getCity());
    }
%>
```

**UPDATE**

Now when i have a list of data, how to display only 1 row clicking on href in new jsp. I have something like that but when i click id isnt passing :

```
 for(CustomerBean list1 : list) {
        out.println("<td>"+list1.getCustomer_id()+"</td>");
        out.println("<td>"+list1.getName()+"</td>");
        out.println("<td>"+list1.getPhone()+"</td>");
        out.println("<td>"+list1.getEmail()+"</td>");
        out.println("<td>"+list1.getCity()+"</td>");
        out.println("<td><a href='details.jsp?customer_id='+list1.getCustomer_id()>details</a></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
    }
```

Comment: Don't code business logic in JSP pages .

Comment: @soorapadman what business logic has OP done in JSP?

Comment: Instead of   request.getSession().setAttribute("list", list); use   request.setAttribute("list", list); in servlet file

Comment: @NehaShettar that doesnt work ;/

Comment: In which you are getting Null Pointer exception.. in servlet or jsp?

Comment: Also try getting list using session in jsp i.e ArrayList<CustomerBean> list = (ArrayList<CustomerBean>) session.getAttribute("list")

Comment: ok i got it and its working :) in servlet i have request.getSession().setAttribute("list", list); response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); and in jsp session.getAttribute("list");

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your `list` to your session

```
 request.getSession().setAttribute("list", list);
```

but trying to retrieve it from your request

```
ArrayList<CustomerBean> list = (ArrayList<CustomerBean>) request.getAttribute("list");
```

try adding it to you `request`

```
request.setAttribute("list", list);
```

Comment: Still NullPointerException :(